# Generate a Unique Order Number (Human Readable) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, numbers, e-commerce, uid

What I'm struggling to find a way to create a Unique Readable Order Number for eCommerce.
Most of them out there are very long and very hard to read.

My backend for this eCommerce is firebase, and the document IDs are too complicated to use as an ID.

Are there any know standards/examples I can follow?

Comment: There's no standard for that. you can use and random string generator to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from js-frameworks benchmarks' code

It's COMPLETELY NOT SAFE for uniqueness, but take it as a general idea.

```js
        var adjectives = ["pretty", "large", "big", "small", "tall", "short", "long", "handsome", "plain", "quaint", "clean", "elegant", "easy", "angry", "crazy", "helpful", "mushy", "odd", "unsightly", "adorable", "important", "inexpensive", "cheap", "expensive", "fancy"];
        var colours = ["red", "yellow", "blue", "green", "pink", "brown", "purple", "brown", "white", "black", "orange"];
        var nouns = ["table", "chair", "house", "bbq", "desk", "car", "pony", "cookie", "sandwich", "burger", "pizza", "mouse", "keyboard"];

function createRandomName = () => random(adjectives) + '-' + random(colours) + '-' + random(nouns) + '-' + new Date().getMilliseconds();
```

It seems random enough, only verify for non-duplicates.